# using custom font in css?

Tags: css, fonts

can someone please help, i am trying to generate a custom font in css which i have downloaded.

i have been reading up on this code which should work but i think i may be doinig it wrong.

my font is called: ShadowsIntoLight.ttf

i'm trying to make it the font family of my div social_header.

here's my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ShadowsIntoLight;
    src: url('assets/fonts/ShadowsIntoLight.ttf');
}

social_header {
font: 100% 'ShadowsIntoLight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;

}
```

Comment: Also double check your `path`. Is your `/assets` folder inside your '/css' directory or do you need to go up one? Use dev tools to see if your browser is reading correctly

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you are identifying your `social_header` div correctly.  There are a variety of ways to do this but some samples are below.

If social_header is an ID:

```
#social_header { ... }
```

If social_header is a class:

```
.social_header { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Input this code in head of your HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

css:

```
font-family: 'ShadowsIntoLight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

first, just check the path to your ttf ,
than try this :

```
.social_header {
    font-size:  12px;
    font-family: ShadowsIntoLight, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ; 
}
```